# Opt into vs opt in to

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs, verb-phrases

On [the site 'Writing Explained'](https://writingexplained.org/into-vs-in-to-difference) it is recommended to use "in to" instead of "into" when "in" is part of a verb phrase. As such, I would conclude that the phrase "opt in to" would be preferred over "opt into", since "opt in" forms the verb phrase. However, "opt into" is referenced by the [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/opt-in).

Any thoughts? Are both forms correct?

Comment: Paul, that's about context, not about using one *instead of* the other.

For example if the question was *How did you vote* the answer might be *I opted in* and it might also be *I opted into the (whatever).*

Is that difference clear, please?

Comment: FWIW, I agree with you (OP), for the reason you gave.

Comment: Thanks Robbie, I agree with you that based on the context one form could be preferable over the other. To give a bit more context, in this particular instance the sense was to enroll into something, such as to enroll into paperless bank statements.

Comment: Paul, the differences in use between *opt* and *enroll* make them a sorry choice for a question like that.

To keep it simple could you leave both them and Writing Explained and Macmillan aside and go back to what how your two or three next favourite dictionaries explain the difference between *in* and *into?

Answer (score 2):

The OED gives what, at first sight, appears to be a distinction without a difference:

> **1. intransitive. To decide for one of two or more alternatives; to choose to do something;**
>
> 1984   A. N. Wilson Hilaire Belloc i. iii. 53   *He opted..to read
> Modern History.*
>
> 2001   B. Geddes World Food: Caribbean 17 (caption)    *Rachel Harms
> **opts for** calm and a strawberry daiquiri despite an impending cyclone.*
>
> **3.a.** intransitive. **to opt in: to choose to participate in something.**
>
> 1966   ‘A. Hall’ 9th Directive i. 12   *A man wants to opt out; they have to give him an incentive that will make him **opt in** again.*
>
> 1993   Times Educ. Suppl. 5 Mar. (Review Suppl.) 2/1   *Every
> 11-year-old in the selective area of Buckinghamshire is put forward
> for the 12-plus unless his or her parents opt out. (In Milton Keynes,
> where there are comprehensives, they have to **opt in**.)*

> **b.** intransitive. **to opt into: to choose to participate in.**
>
> 1996   W. Hutton State we're In (rev. ed.) xii. 310   *The
> voucher-holders are enabled to opt **into** the world of work and
> training.*
>
> 2002   San Antonio Business Jrnl. (Nexis) 13 Sept. 7   *Electric
> cooperatives..are exempt from this competition unless they chose to
> opt **in to** the fray.*

However, note that in 3a nothing follows "in", whereas in 3b a noun phrase must follow into/in to.

That said **to opt** can be seen as an intransitive verb that requires an adverbial complement (Cf. the verb "to put"), i.e. in; out; {into something}, or {for something}.

**In** (adv. and prep.) is usually locative in the sense of "inside" *"He's usually in (prep) his room, in fact, I'm sure he's in (adv.)"*

**Into** is only a preposition and is used with verbs of motion and change of state: *"The ice changed into water" "He went into the cave."* Thus we can say *I was given the opportunity to join the team and I opted in,* but not **"I was given the opportunity to join the team and I opted into".*

As far as **into** and **in to** are concerned, they are used indiscriminately but the former cannot be used with purpose clauses and infinitives: **"I didn't want to be a member of the club but I opted into join the team".*

Answer (score 0):

**to opt in and to opt out**: these are set phrasal verbs. So using into would be a mistake.

They opted in to the scheme to save money.

They opted in to paying the higher rate for better coverage.

AND
They opted out of the scheme as it was too expensive.
We opted out of the coverage because we didn't need it.

See:  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/opt-in)